# 'try' can decide when a program halts

Tags: haskell, halting-problem

I have this function:

```
isUndefined :: () -> Bool    
isUndefined x = case unsafePerformIO $ (try (return $! x) :: IO (Either SomeException ())) of
                    Left _ -> True
                    Right _ -> False
```

then:

```
isUndefined () = False
isUndefined undefined = True
```

Solving the halting problem. Of course, this can be extended to other types too.

My question: how is this possible? Is `Control.Exception.try` really breaking things here?

Comment: A program may enter an infinite loop, not returning either `()` nor `undefined`. Then your `isUndefined` function also enter an infinite loop, not giving any meaningful result, thus it doesn't answer the halting problem. Remember the halting problem receives a program (function, Turing machine, procedure, whatever) as input, not data.

Comment: Do you mean you solve the halting problem by running a program and wait until it halts ????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is Control.Exception.try really breaking things here?

`unsafePerformIO` is breaking things here. In GHC, `undefined` simply raises an exception rather than looping forever (which would be unhelpful). Exceptions are not meant to be caught in pure (non-IO) code -- indeed the type system indeed prevents you to attempt as much.

By using `unsafe*` functions, you are telling GHC "ignore everything, I know what I'm doing", and all the safety belts are now off. Do yourself a favour and pretend that `unsafe*` stuff does not exist.

Comment: Is unsafe* really the one to blame? Try can print as a result whether the program given halts or not. I thought exceptions should not be caught at all.

Comment: @Brrch Exception catching can only be done in the IO monad, which in acts also acts as a "sin-bin", collecting most of the warts. Indeed, exceptions are not a terribly elegant mechanism, IMHO, but since their use is limited to the IO monad, it does not break any important properties in the pure (IO-free) part.